# Ошибка при заносе информации в БД

Tags: база-данных, php

> Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Объясните, пожалуйста, что это за ошибка и как ее исправить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это значит, что в запросе INSERT вы указали полей больше или меньше, чем значений. Такую ошибку в равной степени вызовет

```
INSERT INTO table (field1, field2) VALUES ('1');
```

и

```
INSERT INTO table (field1) VALUES ('1', '2');
```